# c program to count lines in file using system calls

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to count the lines in files using system calls like open(), read(), write() close(). The same program I did with library calls fopen(), fread(), fwrite() and was working great, but with just system calls, I am stuck.

```
int fd1;    // file descriptor
fd1=open("f1.txt",O_RDONLY);   // opening file
read(fd1, buffer , 1);   // reading 1 byte from file
// now comparing
if (buffer == '\n')
line++;
```

My problem is here:

> if (myb == '\n')

I do not know how to compare data from buffer. I am trying to use buffer, but no success. Kindly help!

Comment: What is `myb`? It doesn't appear anywhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: myb   is buffer  (mybuffer ... myb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compared a pointer (`buffer`) to char (`'\n'`)

You should dereference the pointer, for example:

```
if (*buffer == '\n')
```

or

```
if (buffer[0] == '\n')
```

Comment: He's only using a 1-char buffer, so buffer could be a simple `char` (and the name would still be suitable) in which case the solution would instead be `read(fd1, & buffer , 1);`.

Comment: In such case the call `read(fd1, buffer , 1);` will probably fall, as buffer is not a valid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The system calls don't do any buffering except what you supply, so you *really* don't want to read only one byte at a time with them. Up to a point, bigger buffers are better, but past a few kilobytes (or so) increasing the buffer size only gains a *little* more performance in return for using quite a lot more memory.

```
char buffer[16384];
int bytes_read;
unsigned lines = 0;

int fd1 = open("name.txt", O_RDONLY);

while (bytes_read = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<bytes_read; i++)
        if (buffer[i] == '\n')
            ++lines;
}
```

Comment: @user114500: I'm looking for typos in that part of my code, or any differences between what I posted and your comment. I seem to be missing it if there's a difference.

Comment: i want to add one more feature to my program . to count words can anybody will tell me how to count words in file

Comment: Basically you count transitions from whitespace to something else (or vice versa). With `read` you have to manage the buffer carefully, because the end of the buffer could happen mid-word, mid-whitespace, or right at a transition.

Answer (score -1):

well here i solution how to count words in file

```
while(sc !=EOF)
{
sc=fgetc(at);    // at is file stream 

        if(isspace(sc)) sp=1;
        else if(sp) {
            ++words;
        sp=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Words are not lines, and while `isspace` will match the newline character, it will also match tabs, and spaces. Also `fgetc` is a stdio function, not a system call as you originally requested.